# Show grouped column in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am showing this below result in my gridview after querying from the DB.

```
Canada           Ontario      Cambridge
Canada           Ontario      Halton
Canada           Ontario      Hamilton
Canada           Ontario      Milton
United Kingdom    Wales       Bangor
United Kingdom    Wales       Cardiff
United Kingdom    Wales       New Port
United Kingdom    Wales       Swansea
United States     CA          Los Angeles
United States     CA          Merced
United States     CA          Morgan Hill
United States     CA          San Francisco
```

I have worked on gridview, but how could I possibly show result in gridview like this

```
Canada           Ontario     Cambridge
                             Halton
                             Hamilton
                             Milton
United Kingdom    Wales      Bangor
                             Cardiff
                             New Port
                             Swansea
United States     CA         Los Angeles
                             Merced
                             Morgan Hill
                             San Francisco
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Try merging cell... [Rows and Columns Merging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/249155/Rows-and-Columns-Merging-in-ASP-NET-GridView-Contr)

Answer (score 3):

[This is the best link which can help you](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34337/How-to-merge-cells-with-equal-values-in-a-GridView)

```
public class GridDecorator
{
public static void MergeRows(GridView gridView)
{
    for (int rowIndex = gridView.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
    {
        GridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[rowIndex];
        GridViewRow previousRow = gridView.Rows[rowIndex + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            if (row.Cells[i].Text == previousRow.Cells[i].Text)
            {
                row.Cells[i].RowSpan = previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan < 2 ? 2 : 
                                       previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan + 1;
                previousRow.Cells[i].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
protected void gridView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridDecorator.MergeRows(gridView);
}
```

Comment: That is a nice, decent solution. How does it work with sorting by clicking on the headers?

Comment: @PatrickHofman the link i provide will give you description about the algo how to cell can be merge

Comment: @vicky if this answer/solution help you then don't forget to accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by grouping the results in the database (by using `lag` and `lead` functions to compare to the previous row. You could also use a custom control like Infragistics UltraGrid for this, which works fine for us, but that is a paid solution.